# How to detect language of an array item using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to detect language of an array item using `javascript`?
using plain `js` or any `jquery`/`js` libraries or any online api/sdk

```
let voice = 'US English Female';
const lang = detectlanguagesomehow(array.item);
switch (lang) {
  case 'en':
    voice = "US English Female";
    break;
  case 'ar':
    voice = "Arabic Female";
    break;
  default:
    voice = "US English Female";
    break;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "detect language"? Just recognize simple keywords like `US` or `EN` or similar? Or to analyze some free-form text (similar to how Google translate can analyzes text to detect language)? The first is easy. The second is *very* hard.

Comment: its some text that user inputs it can be  either arabic / english . i need to specify which language it has to be read out by tts.

Comment: I have a feeling that *any* solution will do :)

Comment: Will the Arabic text be input using Arabic characters? Or transliterated into Latin characters? If it's Arabic characters it also easy to detect, as it's encoding will be different, and you can just check that.

Answer (score 0):

### Browser settings (recommended)

[`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language)

### Detect from string

Aside: Many caveats; ask yourself why you **really** need to do this.

#### 3rd-party lib

e.g.: https://github.com/wooorm/franc

#### API

e.g. [Google Translate language detection](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/quickstart#language_detect)

Comment: cz the tts only reads out if i specified in which language the sentence is passed to it

Comment: i will check out the 3rd-party lib since im not planning to pay for whole google cloud platform.

Comment: If you really must, 3rd-party lib is your best option. If you're certain it'll just be en and ar, `whitelist` those two languages. Otherwise, you may return things not covered in your switch statement (default to English). The downside is of course, if it *isn't* en/ar, it'll force a return in one of those languages.

Comment: how do i install https://github.com/wooorm/franc this one inside a website

Comment: It's a standard npm package (`npm install franc`). Use Browserify if you need to use it on the front-end.

Comment: var ENGLISH = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ";

    function stringIsEnglish(str) {
    var index;

    for (index = str.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    if (ENGLISH.indexOf(str.substring(index, index + 1)) < 0) {
    return false;
    }
    }
    return true;
    }